# CakePHP saveAll multiple associated models at same time

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having a bit of a problem with saveAll, however I have a feeling what I am trying to do isn't possible but would be interested to see what people think.

The models in question are

```
League
Team
User
```

The relationships are as follows:

**LEAGUE**
One league can have many teams, however the league is owned by one user (the admin).

```
var $belongsTo = 'User';
var $hasMany = 'Team';
```

**TEAM**
Each team can be in one league and be owned by one user.

```
var $belongsTo = array('User', 'League' => array('counterCache' => true));
```

**USER**
Each user can be admin for multiple leagues and also have multiple teams

```
var $hasMany = array('League', 'Team');
```

I have a form where by a user can create a new league, create a team to add to the league and also register. The data that gets posted back to CakePHP is as follows:

```
array(
    'League' => array(
        'name' => 'Valid League Name',
        'max_teams' => '10'
    ),
    'Team' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Valid Team Name'
        )
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => 'password1',
        'firstname' => 'Firstname',
        'lastname' => 'Lastname',
        'email' => 'test@example.com',
        'confirm_password' => 'password1'
    )
);
```

Now assuming this all passes validation and this is the first data entered in to the database I would expect the following to be returned from the saveAll operation that I am using:

```
array(
    'League' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Valid League Name',
        'max_teams' => '10',
        'user_id' => 1
    ),
    'Team' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Valid Team Name',
            'league_id' => 1,
            'user_id' => 1
        )
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'password' => 'password1',
        'firstname' => 'Firstname',
        'lastname' => 'Lastname',
        'email' => 'test@example.com',
        'confirm_password' => 'password1'
    )
);
```

What is happening however is that the `user_id` field in the `Team` array isn't getting populated and it just coming back instead as `null`. What I am guessing is that CakePHP can't be sure that the team and the user that have just been created are necessarily related to one another so haven't created the association between the two.

At the moment, within the controller where the save is being made (I am saving through the League model `$this->League->saveAll()`) I am manually getting the `user_id` once everything has been saved and resaving the team with the new `user_id`. Is there anything I can do to get Cake to realise that the two are associated to the saveAll function does everything I need? I have tried using `saveAll()` with the `deep` option enabled and this also has no affect.

Comment: Please post the actual save operation you're using and whta context it's in.

Comment: I just added that actually as I had a thought a second ago which might answer my problem. At the moment I am saving through the League controller (`$this->League->saveAll()`) if I were to save through the Team controller it might work? Will have a play.

Comment: It should, but also Team shouldn't be within 2 arrays if you're just saving 1 team.

Comment: That didn't work either, saving through `Team` means that the `League` doesn't associate the `User` to itself. `Team` does need to be within 2 arrays when saving with `League` as `League` can have multiple teams - if I take it out of the array it won't save/validate properly.

Comment: "Team does need to be within 2 arrays...when saving with League"  Right - but you said you were going to save through Team (Model, not Controller btw).

Comment: Oh sorry, crossed wires - I thought you were referring to the example in the question. I have tried saving through the `Team` model however that didn't work either as the `League` didn't associate with the `User`.

Comment: And you're trying to CREATE the team, league, AND user all in the single saveAll()?  Ie none of them exist already?

Comment: Indeed - there will be some cases where the user is already registered/logged in so obviously I'll have the user id at that point but there are some cases where the user is also new so would like to be able to do everything in one save operation.

Comment: A lot of problems with save operations come from incorrectly formatted data.  Try putting another array around the data you're trying to save: `array(array('League' => array(), 'Team' => array(array()), 'User' => array()))`  You may also need to set deep to true: `$this->League->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));`

Comment: I had tried using `deep = true` previously but it didn't have an affect. Added this in to the question, tried adding an array around the data that didn't help either. The data is being sent in from form fields produced by Cake so I think everything is formatted correctly.